# Allocate number of columns to repeater when the page is loaded

Tags: asp.net, dataset

I am binding a dataset to asp repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptDataset" runat="server">
<table>
<HeaderTemplate>
<tr>
<th>Col1</th>
<th>Col2</th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td><%# Eval("c1") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("c2") %></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now I have varying number of columns, that won't be known until the page is loaded. So I'm modifying the header like this

```
<HeaderTemplate>
<tr>
<th>Col1</th>
<th>Col2</th>
<% for (int i=0; i<NoOfColumn; i++){ 
Response.Write("<th>ColN</th>")
} % >
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

Which correctly showed all column headers.

What should I modify `<ItemTemplate>` so it could show all the column data?

I've tried something like

```
<% Response.Write("<td><%# Eval("c1") %></td>") %>
```

which would result an error due to the nested <% %> sign.

Also tried

```
<% Response.Write(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "c1")) %>
```

but it said Container cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have it solved by applying nested Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptRow">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
  <td><%# Eval("c1") %></td>
  <td><%# Eval("c2") %></td>
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCol">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <td><%# Eval("cn") %></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
  </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have two options, quick hack and proper pretty solution.

**Quick hack**

Create all necessary html in a string and output it in Literal control. Make sure to use `PassThrough` mode not to have html encoded:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# GetDataRow(Container.DataItem) %>
</ItemTemplate>

protected string GetDataRow(object dataItem)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.Append("<tr>");
    for (int i=0; i<NoOfColumn; i++)
    {
        output.Append("<td>");
        output.Append(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "c"+i));
        output.Append("</td>");
    }
    output.Append("</tr>");
    return output.ToString();
}
```

**Pretty solution**

Define your own custom template implementing `ITemplate`. A complete example of how this is done can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/945563/728795). It will take more work, but, as it's usually the case with pretty solutions, result will be much more readable, maintainable and reusable.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei. The quick hack would work, but it'll be too messy as I'm working on a large dataset. I've read the link - it seems he's allocating columns on the go, which can also be done using DataGrid isn't it? And yet I can't find how the frontend would be shown dynamically. Correct me if I'm wrong.